# Templating infowindow via javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, symfony, twig

Is there a templating best-practice for infowindows inside google-maps?

My problem is:
I have over 100 markers. And all of them have exactly the same structure. I don't want to have the structure of the infowindow inside javascript like this:

```
function showInfowindow(marker, object) {
  var html = "<table><tr><td>" + object.name + "</td><td>" + obj.id </td></tr></table>";
  infoWindow.setContent(html);
  infoWindow.open(map, marker); // map is global defined
}
```

I know there are some helper frameworks (i think jquery has also something) to easily create html with append and prepend functions. But my purpose would be something like a HTML file which has placeholders.

I found something similar inside Symfony2 Bundle VichGeographicalBundle:
https://github.com/dustin10/VichGeographicalBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#popup-info-windows

But integrating to this is not an option (I looked into the output, it generates javascript variables, similar to the `html` variable above)

I'm also interested to some `twig` solutions if they are any.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this source is of some help: http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/

Comment: It's a cool library, but it does not solve my problem, does it?